# ¿Cómo puedo lanzar un evento de botón seleccionado entre clases?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android con Kotlin. Quiero que esta tenga las mejores prácticas posibles, por lo que estoy usando MVVM y Clean Architecture. El inconveniente que estoy teniendo es el siguiente:

Tengo este fragmento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve, tengo dos recyclerViews. En el primero tendría opciones para recoger un pedido en la tienda física y en el segundo por si quiero que me lo envíen a casa. Ambos recyclerViews utilizan un mismo adaptador y un mismo viewHolder, pues son lo mismo.

Quisiera que ambos actuaran como si fuese uno solo (no lo hago con un solo recycler porque quiero mantener ese diseño justamente y porque son peticiones diferentes). Es decir, que si selecciona un elemento en "Recoger en el lugar" se deseleccionen todos en "Domicilio" y viceversa. El problema está en que no sé qué evento manejar ni cómo hacerlo para que esto suceda. Intenté con las interfaces View.OnClickListener y CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener pero no, simplemente no obtengo respuesta de llamada de ese método.

Las 3 clases son las siguientes:

La que gestiona directamente el XML, el fragmento

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class SelectShippingOptionsFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentShippingOptionsBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val selectShippingOptionsViewModel: SelectShippingOptionsViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentShippingOptionsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        setUpComponents()
        listDataShippingOptions()
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setUpComponents(){
        binding.headerWithButton.textViewTitleProduct.text = Constants.SELECT_SHIPPING_OPTION
        binding.headerWithButton.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener{
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.navigation_select_shipping_option)
        }
        binding.buttonContinue.setOnClickListener{
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Continue")
        }
    }

    private fun listDataShippingOptions() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val pickUpAddresses = selectShippingOptionsViewModel
                .getDataShippingList(Constants.PICK_UP_DATA_SHIPPING_REQUEST).toMutableList()
            val atHomeAddresses = selectShippingOptionsViewModel
                .getDataShippingList(Constants.AT_HOME_DATA_SHIPPING_REQUEST).toMutableList()
            
            for(dataShipping in pickUpAddresses){
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, dataShipping.toString())
            }

            for(dataShipping in atHomeAddresses){
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, dataShipping.toString())
            }

            val layoutManagerPickUp = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            val layoutManagerAtHome = LinearLayoutManager(context)


            var adapterRecyclerViewPickUpOnSite = DataShippingAdapter(pickUpAddresses)

            binding.recyclerviewPickUpOnSite.layoutManager = layoutManagerPickUp
            binding.recyclerviewPickUpOnSite.adapter = adapterRecyclerViewPickUpOnSite


            binding.recyclerviewAtHome.layoutManager = layoutManagerAtHome
            binding.recyclerviewAtHome.adapter = DataShippingAdapter(atHomeAddresses)


        }
    }

}
```

El adaptador

```
class DataShippingAdapter(
    private val dataShippingList: List<DataShipping>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DataShippingViewHolder>() {

     var lastCheckedPosition = -1
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DataShippingViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return DataShippingViewHolder(
            layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.shipping_option_item, parent, false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dataShippingList.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DataShippingViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.render(dataShippingList[position])
        holder.binding.radiobutton.isChecked = position == lastCheckedPosition
        holder.binding.radiobutton.setOnClickListener{
            lastCheckedPosition = holder.absoluteAdapterPosition
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, holder.binding.textViewName.text.toString())
            notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    }

}
```

Y el ViewHolder

```
class DataShippingViewHolder(view : View) : ViewHolder(view){

    val binding = ShippingOptionItemBinding.bind(view)
    fun render(dataShipping: DataShipping) {
        binding.textViewName.text = dataShipping.name
        binding.textViewAddress.text = "${dataShipping.address} - ${dataShipping.municipality}, ${dataShipping.department}"
        binding.textViewPhone.text = dataShipping.phone.toString()
    }

}
```

Para hacer un poco más claro lo que quiero decir, aquí tengo una imagen de la aplicación en un celular.

Como se observa, tengo dos recyclerview. Si la persona selecciona uno de los elementos de la lista de la parte superior (en este caso solo hay uno) y hay alguno seleccionado de la lista inferior, debería deseleccionarse.

[image]

Como se observa, tengo dos recyclerview. Si la persona selecciona uno de los elementos de la lista de la parte superior (en este caso solo hay uno) y hay alguno seleccionado de la lista inferior, debería deseleccionarse.

Comment: Me perdí. ¿Quieres que al tocar un elemento de una lista se deseleccione el de la otra lista? Tal vez esto te ayude mientras aclaras la pregunta. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30046476/13419694

Comment: Lo siento por la confusión en la pregunta. Añadí una imagen que puede clarificar lo que estoy queriendo hacer. Respecto al link que proporcionaste... creo que no, no es lo que busco. Aún así, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo agregaría un listener y una función pública en el `Adapter` para poder deseleccionar el `RecyclerView` desde fuera.

```
interface OnSelectedChangedListener {
    fun onSelectedChanged(view: View)
}

class DataShippingAdapter(
    private val dataShippingList: List<DataShipping>,
    private val onSelectedChangedListener: OnSelectedChangedListener
):

...

    fun deselect() {
        lastCheckedPosition = -1
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Además modificaría la función `onBindViewHolder` llamando el listener.

```
holder.binding.radiobutton.setOnClickListener {
    val position = holder.absoluteAdapterPosition
    if (position == lastCheckedPosition)
        return
    // La idea es salir del callback si la posición no cambió.
    // No estoy seguro si hay que agregar @algo al return.

    lastCheckedPosition = position
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, holder.binding.textViewName.text.toString())
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    onSelectedChangedListener(this);
}
```

Entonces en tu Fragment implementas la `OnSelectedChangedListener` y también pasas `this` al constructor del Adapter.

```
fun onSelectedChanged(view: View) {
    if (view == recycler1) {
        recycler2.deselect()
    }
    else {
        recycler1.deselect()
    }
}
```